# How to remove persistent Lethic/B trojan - Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, virus, trojan

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Conficker.Exe Removal](https://superuser.com/questions/51519/conficker-exe-removal)
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Free AV that came with my Windows XP computer expired and I was a bit tardy in updating. Now have a Lethic/B infection. Tried the following:

- Trend Micro housecall
- Boot safe mode run (latest) Avira command line tool
- Install Microsoft Security Essentials

Now every day after booting, the Microsoft AV pops up a little message to say it's found two infections, one Lethic/B and the other varies. I take the option to "clean" but it's back again next day. How do I clear this infection completely?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware). To sum up... I would take out the hard drive and scan it from another computer (without booting into the infected operating system) using Microsoft security essentials... since it appears to be able to detect it. Scanning the drive with a few other products like avg, avast, malwarebytes, and spybot search and destroy couldn't hurt either. This technique has solved the reoccurring virus issue for me many times.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the order given below to properly disinfect your PC

1.) Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.

.

Comment: thanks for the techmixer link. I'll try one of those bootable CD options.
I'm dubious about MBAB. Must install MBAM and boot from the HD to run it. I suspect I'm working with something nasty here (rootkit?) so it would probably evade MBAM.